# How do I create rows in an output file?

Tags: c++, loops, ofstream

I currently have this code and all of the formatting is correct... I just can't seem to get it to create rows in the output text file... How would I do this? I've tried to do a for loop in the function and in the main() but it seems to not work if I do that so I am very confused right now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void output(string flightnumber, int arrival1, int arrival2, int realarrival1, int realarrival2, char dummy1, char dummy2)
{
    ofstream flight;
    flight.open("flightdata.dat");

    if (flight.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error..." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "Enter the flight number: ";
    cin >> flightnumber;

    if (flightnumber == "end")
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    flight << flightnumber << setw(4);

    cout << "Enter the scheduled/actual arrival times (hh:mm hh:mm):";

    cin >> arrival1 >> dummy1 >> arrival2 >> realarrival1 >> dummy2 >> realarrival2;
    flight << arrival1 << dummy1 << arrival2 << setw(4) << realarrival1 << dummy2 << realarrival2;
    flight << ('\n');
}

int main()
{
    string flightnumber;
    int arrival1, arrival2, realarrival1, realarrival2;
    char dummy1, dummy2;

    output(flightnumber, arrival1, arrival2, realarrival1, realarrival2, dummy1, dummy2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it seems to not work" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: Not all editors treat a single new line char as a line break. Something like notepad is going to want to see a carriage return '\r' and a new line char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using uninitialized variables in `main`. They serve no purpose in there anyway. Remove variable declarations from `main` and put them in `output`:

```
void output()
{
    string flightnumber;
    int arrival1, arrival2, realarrival1, realarrival2;
    char dummy1, dummy2;

    ofstream flight;
    flight.open("c:\\test\\___flightdata.txt", ios::app);
    ...
}

int main()
{
    output();
    return 0;
}
```

You may want to add `ios::app` flag as pointed out in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are not appending your file whenever you write it truncates and creates a new file, add appending flag and open your file as.

```
flight.open("flightdata.dat", ios_base::app);
```